# How do I get the UTC offset for __TIME__?

Tags: time, c99

We are using `__TIME__` to embed the time of compilation in a binary. Unfortunately, a time without a UTC Offset is meaningless. I don't see an obvious way to get the timezone that the compiler is running in. I suppose I could grab this from the configure script. But is there a better way?

If I do it from a configure script, I'm going to need to put that into a .h or .c file somehow, and do something intelligent if the file is not there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use compiler Flags to pass that externally. Most compiler provide `'-D'` flag to define `#define` macros externally. Let's suppose you put the UTC information in an environment variable. Pass that environment variable as `-D` flag

```
set $myUTC="-7"
gcc -c mysource.cpp -DUTC=$myUTC
```

In your `mysource.cpp`  use the macro `UTC`:

```
printf("Compiled at %d Offset %d", __TIME__, UTC);
```

Comment: Okay, so the configure script has to get the offset from the time that it's run, and we just assume that the configure script and the compiler run in the same timezone. I guess that works. Now the only remaining problem is that the `date` command doesn't provide UTC offset, so I need to find it some other way. Still, this seems like a kludge.

Comment: will your script be running on various timezones? if not then you can place it  yourself instead of finding it through command.

Comment: A better option would be use the output of the `date` command with the UTC switch and the desired format.